# Wrong transformation between British National Grid and WGS84

Tags: postgis, proj, united-kingdom, ordnance-survey, transform

I have access to a remote DB with the following specifications:

*PostgreSQL 11.12*

*POSTGIS="2.5.2 r17328" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.0-CAPI-1.11.0 673b9939" PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018" GDAL="GDAL 2.3.1, released 2018/06/22" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.12.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.0" TOPOLOGY RASTER*

I also have the following polygon in British National Grid (27700):

```
select st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON ((624172 308463.88, 624168.25 308465.95, 624172.25 308473.05, 624169.3 308474.62, 624161 308459.58, 624166.68 308456.55, 624172 308463.88))', 27700)
```

When I transform the polygon to 4326, it is completely misaligned with the base map layer. Here I use ESRI Topo layer because it seems to be better aligned with UK data.

```
select st_transform(st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON ((624172 308463.88, 624168.25 308465.95, 624172.25 308473.05, 624169.3 308474.62, 624161 308459.58, 624166.68 308456.55, 624172 308463.88))', 27700), 4326)
```

[image]

When I run this query, I have no choice of picking a separate transformation so I assume the default transformation between 27700 and 4326 is being used.

However, if I load the same polygon to QGIS I am given the choice to pick between various transformations:
[image]

Both OSTN02 & OSTN15 transformations were downloaded from [Ordnance Survey](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/for-developers) and installed the .gsb files locally.
Since OSTN15 is considered the most accurate, I used it to transform the polygon and the result aligns better with the base map:

[image]

This is how the 2 transformations compare to each other:
[image]

Since the database is remote, I cannot install a .gsb file with the correct transformation nor add any extension.

My question is: Is there a way to use the correct transformation within my query?

If I look at the projections in the DB:

```
SELECT * FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 27700
```

I get this projection:

+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs

Is there another, more accurate, proj4text I could use?

Comment: if you can't install the gsb file I doubt you can write to the spatial_ref table either. Just ask the remote operator to install the gsb file, it will help all their GB users

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through a couple of transformations to achieve an accurate representation of your data (as well as using the OSTN file)
Try this:

ST_Transform(ST_Transform(ST_SETSRID(geom,27700),4277),4326) as geom_4326_WGS84